# TSQL from OPENJONS() with an explicit schema: empty string in decimal(38,30) data type

Tags: json, sql-server

**I can't get `from openjson()` to cast, convert, or recognize a `decimal(38,30)` datatype when it is an empty string.  I must, for some reason, explicitly declare it as `varchar(39)`.  Why?**  Otherwise, I get the error, `Error converting data type varchar to numeric`, and I will explain further:

I'm ultimately building an UPDATE statement, but I've simplified the example shown in this SO question. This temp table corresponds to my real destination table; the datatypes are exact.

```
declare @tmpSchedules table (
    [EffectDate] [smalldatetime] null,
    [Description] [varchar](30) null,
    [Calculated] [bit] not null,
    [BaseSchedule] [varchar](9) null,
    [Factor] [decimal](38, 30) null
    )
```

This is my incoming data.  It's a JSON string.  Note that the Factor could be: 1) totally missing from the structure, 2) an empty string, or 3) a `decimal(38,30)` value.

```
declare @jsonRequest nvarchar(max) =
'{
    "EffectDate": "2021-04-01",
    "Description": "",
    "Calculated": "",
    "Factor": "",
    "BaseSchedule": null
}'

/*
        ==FACTORS==

NULL (missing from structure)     --->>> from openjson() can handle this

"Factor": "",     --->>> from openjson() CAN NOT handle this!!!

"Factor": "0.411334674542662787386271222800",     --->>> from openjson() can handle this

*/
```

When I declare it as a `decimal`, then it can't be an empty string, or I'll get this:  `Error converting data type varchar to numeric`.  Since it's a `decimal`, I want to declare it as a decimal.  I don't want to declare it as a `varchar`!

Also, I need to select `NULL` if it is either an empty string, or actually null: `nullif(Factor, '') as Factor`

Anyway, I'm having more luck with `json_value()` and `json_query()`, so maybe I should just switch my strategy?

Is the problem my incorrect expectations with `from openjson()`, or is this a cast/convert/datatype issue?

```
select
    EffectDate
    ,Description
    ,Calculated
    ,BaseSchedule
    ,Factor
    --,nullif(Factor, '') as Factor
from openjson(@jsonRequest, '$')
with
(
    EffectDate [smalldatetime] '$.EffectDate'
    ,Description [varchar](30) '$.Description'
    ,Calculated [bit] '$.Calculated'
    ,BaseSchedule [varchar](9) '$.BaseSchedule'
    ,Factor [decimal](38, 30) '$.Factor' --Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
    --,Factor [varchar](39) '$.Factor'

)
```

Comment: An empty string is not a valid decimal literal, it's as simple as that (`CONVERT(DECIMAL(...), '')` isn't legal). This is dubious in JSON itself: a string literal isn't a numeric literal, as the latter don't have quotes. `"0.411334674542662787386271222800"` is a string, not a number (if `Factor` could be `null` or `0.411334674542662787386271222800`, it would convert without issue). In fact, you're basically getting "lucky" that an empty string does convert to `BIT`, or that would be an error too. I'd use `VARCHAR` and then `TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 30), Factor)` in the outer query.

Comment: In fact, the fact that T-SQL applies the rules for string conversion if you feed it JSON strings and then ask for typed data is quite a harmful idea, if you ask me. What do you think the result is if `EffectDate` is the empty string? If you guessed `NULL` or an error, you would be quite mistaken!

Comment: @JeroenMostert OMG you're right about that [smalldatetime] as an empty string, it's a 'new' date 1900-01-01 !!!!  (I do have some control over the incoming data, so I do try to "scrub" and be as explicit as I can when defining the json request).  Thanks!

Comment: @raydlevel5 Similar to my answer below, consume the string of EffectDate and then try_convert(date,nullif(EffectDate,''))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we consume the string for `FACTOR` and then `try_convert` it to the decimal.  This way the empty value will not fail

**Example**

```
declare @jsonRequest nvarchar(max) =
'{
    "EffectDate": "2021-04-01",
    "Description": "",
    "Calculated": "",
    "Factor": "0.411334674542662787386271222800",
    "BaseSchedule": null
}'


select
    EffectDate
    ,Description
    ,Calculated
    ,BaseSchedule
    ,Factor  = try_convert(decimal(38,30),Factor)    --<<< Notice the try_convert()
from openjson(@jsonRequest, '$')
with
(
    EffectDate [smalldatetime] '$.EffectDate'
    ,Description [varchar](30) '$.Description'
    ,Calculated [bit] '$.Calculated'
    ,BaseSchedule [varchar](9) '$.BaseSchedule'
    ,Factor [varchar](39) '$.Factor'
)
```

**Returns**

```
EffectDate              Description Calculated  BaseSchedule    Factor
2021-04-01 00:00:00                 0           NULL            0.411334674542662787386271222800
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer which matches what @JeroenMostert commented.  I should note that it's not necessary for me to use `try_convert`.  It is what it is:  most of the data coming in is being produced as string literals (most of the key values have quotes... numeric values often have quotes), so I guess I'll treat it as such --- a string.  Thanks guys.